# R Travis CI error: Package suggested but not available: ‘ridge’

Tags: r, travis-ci, r-package

I am trying to run Travis CI for one of my R packages. The problem is the build fails with an error stating that one dependency of the package is not available (the package named 'ridge')

Here the error log:

```
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package ‘imputeR’ version ‘2.1’
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Package suggested but not available: ‘ridge’
The suggested packages are required for a complete check.
Checking can be attempted without them by setting the environment
variable _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_ to a false value.
See section ‘The DESCRIPTION file’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’
manual.
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR
See
 ‘/home/travis/build/SteffenMoritz/imputeR/imputeR.Rcheck/00check.log’
for details.
0.38schecking package dependencies ... ERROR
Package suggested but not available: ‘ridge’
```

Here is also the link to the Travis built:
 https://travis-ci.org/SteffenMoritz/imputeR/builds/436334069

The package that is not available to Travis is a normal package that is currently on CRAN. Could this be related to Gnu Scientific Library version >= 1.14 being required for ridge..? Can I somehow solve this problem?

Comment: Try adding:
```r_binary_packages:
  - stringi```
For example, see this `yaml` file:
https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: thx I'll try and report back in some minutes

Comment: mhh did not work out this way. The command "eval sudo apt-get install -y r-cran-ridge " failed. Retrying, 3 of 3. See also https://travis-ci.org/SteffenMoritz/imputeR/builds/437218833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right by saying that it is because ridge requires an external library (Gnu Scientific Library) that is not installed by default on travis.

[Travis CI docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/) explain in detail how you can install external packages.

In your case, you need to add

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages: libgsl0-dev
```

to your `.travis.yml`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that let's at least TRAVIS complete the check

You can add this to the Travis configuration yaml file:

```
env:
 global:
   - _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_: false
```

Downside as far as I understand is:  everything which includes suggested packages is not checked at all. So the solution is not completely satisfying.